# xcode 4.2 memory alloc/dealloc

Tags: iphone, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

hi I have doubts about the xcode 4.2 memory management system. I have read [here](http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php?topic=4939) that in xcode 4 you don't need to worry about memory allocation and also I am doing a tutorial but I get errors each time I refer to alloc of realease or autorelease, like ARC forbids explicit messages of dealloc or things like that. Shall I from now on ignore all reference to alloc dealloc and release? Or is it better to turn off that ARC thing off?? thks in advance for your advice as i am new to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove all release and autorelease function calls. you do not need to call autorelease or release when you select ARC. the iOS will handle it for you

Answer (score 5):

Leaving "that ARC thing" on is the best thing you can do to help yourself avoid countless hours debugging these pesky memory leaks and dangling pointer references. Instead of turning it off, read more about it to get a solid understanding of the feature. CLang people did an OK job [explaining it in their documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), but also there are [other](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html) [places](http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/) where this great new feature is explained in much detail.

Answer (score 3):

Leave ARC on. Then go and read about what ARC is (this might help you - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html). Then you'll understand how to ARC-ify code and you can follow the tutorial at the same time as converting it. In a nutshell, you don't explicitly call `retain`, `release` or `autorelease` when using ARC.